# Not able to get a fielding data which is in json format coming from api in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, api

I want to get data inside the fielding which I want to show on the web
I am able to get till data after that it shows `undefined`
`console.log(currentdata.data[fielding[0].title]);`  when I use to execute this code its shows error of undefined

```
 var request = require("request");
 var cricapi = require("cricapi");
const Runtorun = ({ match }) => {
 const params = match.params;
      console.log(params);
      const currentdata = [];
      async function fetchData() {
        let url =
          "https://cricapi.com/api/fantasySummary?apikey=o7aO0AGvIcd4CMasVKLh0OG4Ijc2&unique_id=";
        const unique_id = params.unique_id;

 console.log(unique_id);
        await fetch(url + unique_id).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => currentdata.push(data));
      }
    console.log(currentdata);
  //  console.log(currentdata.data[fielding[0].title]);
 
 useEffect(() => {
       fetchData();
     });
return (
       <div>
         
       </div>
     );
   };
 export default Runtorun;
```

This is a data coming from API which is pushed in array

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, every time this function runs you are setting current data back to [] by having `const currentdata = []` in the function body, and your `currentdata.push(data)` call happens sometime in the future.

React components have this concept of internal `state` so it can remember values each time the component re-renders and the function runs.

```
const Runtorun = ({ match }) => {
    const params = match.params;

    const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState([]);
    
    const fetchData = () => {
        const url =
            `https://cricapi.com/api/fantasySummary?apikey=o7aO0AGvIcd4CMasVKLh0OG4Ijc2&unique_id=${params.unique_id}`;

        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setCurrentData(...currentDate, data));
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    );
};
```